# Drag&Drop и Click на одном блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    let block = $('div.block');

    let dragObject = {};

                block.mousedown(function (e) {
                    console.log('mousedown');
                    console.log('e.pageX '+e.pageX + ' ' + 'e.pageY '+e.pageY);
                    if (e.which != 1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    let target=$(e.target);
                    if (target.is(block) || target.closest(block).length > 0) {
                        let pOffset = $(e.target).closest(block).offset();
                        console.log('pOffset ');
                        console.log(pOffset);
                        let x = Math.round(e.pageX - pOffset.left);
                        let y = Math.round(e.pageY - pOffset.top);
                        dragObject.x = x;
                        dragObject.y = y;
                        dragObject.e = target.closest(block);
                        localStorage.setItem('relOX', x);
                        localStorage.setItem('relOY', y);
                    }
                });

                block.mouseup(function (e) {
                    console.log('mouseup');
                    if(!dragObject.m) {
                        block.css('background', 'red');
                    } else {
                       let pos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pos'));
                                             block.css({'top': pos.y, 'left': pos.x});
                    }
                    dragObject = {};
                    $('body').removeClass('disable-select');

                });

                $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                    if(!dragObject.e) {
                        delete dragObject.m;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        console.log('mousemove');
                        let relX = Number(localStorage.getItem('relOX'));
                        let relY = Number(localStorage.getItem('relOY'));
                        let x = e.pageX - relX;
                        let y = e.pageY - relY;
                        if (Math.abs(x) < 6 && Math.abs(y) < 6) {
                            delete dragObject.m;
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log('X - '+x+' '+'Y - '+y);
                        localStorage.setItem('pos', JSON.stringify({y: y, x: x}));
                        block.css({'top': y, 'left': x});
                        dragObject.m = block;
                    }
                });

});
```

Есть такое: https://jsfiddle.net/dp39hc4x/25/

Перемещение работает, но простое нажатие нет (при простом нажатии должен измениться цвет).

Подскажите что не так делаю?

Comment: Странно, но  у меня цвет изменился на красный. Что именно не работает, можете более подробно?

Comment: @ЯковЛинг та я уже изменил. Раньше не работало изменение цвета при простом клике. Я двигать блок мог, а простой клик не работал.

Comment: @ЯковЛинг попробуй щас.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let block = $('div.block');

    let dragObject = {};

                block.mousedown(function (e) {
                    console.log('mousedown');
                    //console.log('e.pageX '+e.pageX + ' ' + 'e.pageY '+e.pageY);
                    if (e.which != 1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    let target=$(e.target);
                    if (target.is(block) || target.closest(block).length > 0) {
                        dragObject.downX = e.pageX;
                        dragObject.downY = e.pageY;
                        let coords = getCoords(block);
                        dragObject.shiftX = dragObject.downX - coords.left;
                        dragObject.shiftY = dragObject.downY - coords.top;
                        dragObject.e = target.closest(block);
                    }
                });

                $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                    if(!dragObject.e) {
                        delete dragObject.m;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        console.log('mousemove');
                        console.log(dragObject);

                        let dX = e.pageX - dragObject.downX;
                        let dY = e.pageY - dragObject.downY;
                        if (Math.abs(dX) < 6 && Math.abs(dY) < 6) {
                            return;
                        }

                        let x = e.pageX - dragObject.shiftX;
                        let y = e.pageY - dragObject.shiftY;

                        console.log('X - '+x+' '+'Y - '+y);

                        localStorage.setItem('pos', JSON.stringify({y: y, x: x}));
                        block.css({'top': y, 'left': x});
                        dragObject.m = block;
                    }
                });

                                block.mouseup(function (e) {
                    console.log('mouseup');
                    if(!dragObject.m) {
                            if(block.hasClass('red')) {
                            block.removeClass('red');
                        } else {
                            block.addClass('red');
                        }
                    } else {
                       /*let pos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pos'));
                                             block.css({'top': pos.y, 'left': pos.x});*/
                    }
                    dragObject = {};
                });

});

function getCoords(elem) { // кроме IE8-
  let box = elem.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset
  };

}
```

Решение тут: https://jsfiddle.net/dp39hc4x/28/